# Inheritance in Generics

Tags: c#, generics

How would you make B inherit from A with the following classes?

```
public class A<U>
{

}

public class B<T>
{

}
```

Comment: @leppie Wow, I recognize your name from CodeProject - didn't know that there are CPians that are on SO, too. Great to see!

Comment: Why inherit? How? Best thing may be no inheritance at all.

Comment: @Uwe Keim: Seems a couple people from CP is here  :)

Comment: At first, I thought the question didn't make any sense. Then I read the comments, and now I'm starting to think I'm the clueless one here.

Answer (score 4):

You can inherit like this:

```
public class B<T>:A<T>
{
}
```

This substitutes the genetic parameter `T` of `B` as the generic parameter `U` of `A`. The generic parameters of the base class and derived class are independent. The derived class just needs to specify the parameters it wants in the base class using any types it can name. This includes type-parameters, normal types,... For example you could have `List<KeyValuePair<int,T>>` as base-class if you wanted.

Note that the generic parameter `T` of `B` needs to have enough generic constraints to fulfill the generic constraints of the generic parameter `U` of `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
public class A<U>
{ }

public class B<T,U> : A<U>
{ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple as it is

```
public classB<T>:A<T>  {  }
```

Here's a good reference on this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx